# How to make a database service in Netbeans 6.5 to connect to SQLite databases?

Tags: sqlite, netbeans, jdbc, sqlite2

I use Netbeans IDE (6.5) and I have a SQLite 2.x database. I installed a JDBC SQLite driver from [zentus.com](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) and added a new driver in Nebeans services panel. Then tried to connect to my database file from Services > Databases using this URL for my database:

jdbc:sqlite:/home/farzad/netbeans/myproject/mydb.sqlite

but it fails to connect. I get this exception:

```
org.netbeans.modules.db.dataview.meta.DBException: Unable to Connect to database : DatabaseConnection[name='jdbc:sqlite://home/farzad/netbeans/myproject/mydb.sqlite [ on session]']
    at org.netbeans.modules.db.dataview.output.SQLExecutionHelper.initialDataLoad(SQLExecutionHelper.java:103)
    at org.netbeans.modules.db.dataview.output.DataView.create(DataView.java:101)
    at org.netbeans.modules.db.dataview.api.DataView.create(DataView.java:71)
    at org.netbeans.modules.db.sql.execute.SQLExecuteHelper.execute(SQLExecuteHelper.java:105)
    at org.netbeans.modules.db.sql.loader.SQLEditorSupport$SQLExecutor.run(SQLEditorSupport.java:480)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
```

What should I do? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of Zentus SQLiteJDBC is v053, based on SQLite 3.6.1. It will not open a 2.x SQLite database. Perhaps you can use SQLite 2.x command line tool to .dump your database, and the Sqlite3 command line tool to .load it. The use Zentus SQLiteJDBC to access the new SQLite 3.x database.

Alternatively, use a JDBC driver that supports SQLite 2 such as [this one](http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite/).

Answer (score 0):

It's againg me...

I have made two mistakes during my first attempt. After setting `CLASSPATH` as a system variable (hope I didn’t broke smth else :)), putting `sqlite_jni.dll` to the `system32` folder and correcting `JDBC url` I have got a success :)

I also have downloaded their `SQLite ODBC wrapper`. Installed it and made a connection to my `SQLite2` database via ordinary and `UTF8` based `ODBC` driver. I also used built in `NetBeans JDBC-ODBC` Bridge driver to be able to set up this connection.

All three connections have been created but:

- `ordinary ODBC driver`: I see text data in a wrong encoding. All other columns are displayed correctly
- `UTF8 ODBC driver`: I don’t see text data at all. All other columns are displayed correctly
- `JDBC driver`: I don’t see any column at all. `"Select * from my_any_table"` always returns an empty *single* column

I have Russian based data in my database.

So...currently I have returned to sqlite command line interface :))